# d3 Network with Multiple Links in the Same Direction

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to alter the Mobile Patent Suits example to allow for multiple links in one direction.

I have data (yes, I know Jim isn't actually Pam's boss):

```
source          target          relationship          
Michael Scott   Jan Levenson    pro
Jan Levenson    Michael Scott   personal
Jim Halpert     Pam Beasley     pro
Jim Halpert     Pam Beasley     personal
```

The multi-path functionality of the Mobil Patents Suit example allows the first two rows to be presented correctly (two arcs). However, only one blended arc is presented for the last two rows.

Question: How do I allow links with the same directionality to be shown as multiple arcs rather than a single arc?

Here is my arc code (ripped straight from the Mobile Patents Example):

```
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probable a few potential approaches for this, one comes to mind rather quickly: use a different path generator for each type relationship between the nodes. You'll have to have a property indicating the nature of the relationship  (which you have in your question), and use that to set the path alignment.

In the snippet below I check to see what relationship is being drawn, and reduce the radius of the arc in a personal relationship by 50% as compared to the professional relationship arc radius. The relevant part is:

```
function linkArc(d) {

  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if(d.relationship == "pro") { 
     return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  }
  else {
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + (dr * 0.3) + "," + (dr * 0.3) + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  }
}
```

Here's the whole thing in practice:

```js
var links = [
  { source: "Michael Scott",
    target:"Jan Levenson",
    relationship: "pro"
  },
  { source:"Jan Levenson",
    target:"Michael Scott",
    relationship: "Personal"
  },
  { source: "Jim Halpert",
    target: "Pam Beasley",
    relationship: "pro"
  },
  {
    source: "Jim Halpert",
    target: "Pam Beasley",
    relationship: "Personal" 
  }
  ]
  
  var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {

  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if(d.relationship == "pro") { 
     return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  }
  else {
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + (dr * 0.3) + "," + (dr * 0.3) + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  }
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```