# 2 links (strokes) between 2 nodes in the same direction?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, hierarchy, force-layout

I try to look for a solution to get 2 straight links in the same direction from one node to another in D3.js by using the hierarchy layout (force-layout).
I found this question below, but this is not the answer for my problem because I use the hierarchy layout.
[d3 Network with Multiple Links in the Same Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315707/d3-network-with-multiple-links-in-the-same-direction)

My goal is, to give the strokes different 2 colors, that's why i look for 2 straight links, each link one color. I had problems to implement linear-gradient() on strokes because they are not thick enough. Maybe someone can help

Thank you!

Comment: Derick, please clarify your question: force layout and hierarchy layout are two completely different things.

Comment: Hello Gerardo, yeah, sorry for not beeing clear. How can i explain it. I use the hierachy layout in combination with the force layout. So, that means i use both layouts. I use a Json file and there are never 2 nodes related in both directions to each other. That means, a child node has maximum one parent node.